# Cross domain AJAX call and Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: ajax, csrf

I understand that you are not allowed to make cross domain Ajax calls, but why is it that I can make a cross domain ajax call to facebook's (or twitter or others) oauth API?

Does this have to do with the following?

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"
```

Is allowing all access like this bad practice? Is there a better way to allow only people who you authorize?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[*Access-Control-Allow-Origin* response header field](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-allow-origin-response-header) is part of [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) which allows cross-origin requests with XHR under certain conditions that can be controlled by the server the request is sent to.

In this particular case, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` means that the server allows requests from any origin. This basically means that the resource is publicly available and does not support credentials.

But as you wish to restrict the access to just authorized users, you cannot use `*`. Instead, you need to return the `Origin` header field value (see [section 6.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#resource-requests)). If the client does already have credentials but has not yet requested the resource, you will also need to support [preflight requests](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#resource-preflight-requests) that negotiate what information the client is allowed to send.

Comment: Thanks! I Probably need to read-up on all those links that you pointed me to before I can fully understand your answer.

Comment: @kumikoda Yes, fully understanding CORS is quite complicated. (And I hope my answer is correct.)